# Yii2 dropdown list and array helper "Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on array"

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to understand why my drop down list is not working. I recieve the following error messages when I try to run the custom view related to this model/view/controller.

Please forgive any of my ignorance as I am completely new to PHP and PHP frameworks by proxy.

Site Controller Code:

```
public function actionStudentcentrequiz()
  {
      $model = new GameId();
      $qnamodel = new Questions();
      $listData = ArrayHelper::map(Gameid::find()->all(), 'gameid','gamename');

      if ($qnamodel->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

              //PK FK relation
              $model->gameid = $qnamodel->gameid;

              if ($qnamodel->validate()) {
                  //var_dump($qnamodel); die;
                  //then save.
                  $qnamodel->save();
              }
              //form inputs are valid, do something here
              return;
      }

        return $this->render('studentcentrequiz', [
            'model' => $model,
            'qnamodel' => $qnamodel,
            'listData' => $listData,
        ]);
  }
```

view/questions/_form.PHP

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Questions */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="questions-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'Question')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'Answer1')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'Answer2')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'Answer3')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'Answer4')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'gameid')->dropDownList($listData,['prompt'=>'ChooseGameID']) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

view/questions/_create.PHP

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;


/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Questions */

$this->title = 'Create Questions';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Questions', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="questions-create">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?= $this->render('_form', ['model' => $model, 'listData' => $listData,
     ]) ?>

</div>
```

view/questions/_update.PHP

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Questions */

$this->title = 'Update Questions: ' . $model->questionID;
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Questions', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => $model->questionID, 'url' => ['view', 'id' => $model->questionID]];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = 'Update';
?>
<div class="questions-update">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?= $this->render('_form', ['model' => $model, 'listData' => $listData,]) ?>

</div>
```

Comment: in your controller you render 'studentcentrequiz' view. you did not include the contents of this.

Comment: try change this line of code


`$listData = ArrayHelper::map(Gameid::find()->all()->asArray(), 'gameid','gamename');`

Comment: I will try this today Borisa.

Comment: @ttdijkstra the actual contents of the arrray which I am mapping is part gameID model and part student centre quiz model. The logic is that the user is presented with a list of quiz models which they can edit ad add too. I would just rather a user was presented with the game name in a drop down as opposed to having to manually type in the gameid to successfully complete tthe association.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after 2 hours with the same problem

View:

$form->field($model[0], 'gameid')->dropDownList($listData,['prompt'=>'ChooseGameID'])

Why? i dont know, I would like to someone explain, I have 41 records and both appear the same way in the dropdownlist [0][1][2]...

Comment: Is that because you are selecting the first version of the model? What if you do not pass in a model reference index?